# Python urllib.request.urlopen() only return when given 'timeout' parameter, otherwise freeze forever

Tags: python, web, urllib, urlopen

I'd encountered a strange problem when using `urllib.request.urlopen` function. When I call the function without given the `timeout` parameter, it just freeze forever (or really really long time), but once I provide the `timeout` parameter, eg. `timeout = 1`, the function just return exactly after the interval of `timeout` without any problem.

As shown in the *gif* below. (I was using **Ipython** prompt)

[image: screen record scene of the problem]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found that is an IPv6 problem, after disabled it, everything became fine back.